# Eclipse - how to add a file that has right to left strings

Tags: eclipse, string, editor, right-to-left

I am writing a Java app using Eclipse. This app read a set of Hebrew strings (that are right-to-left). Assuming I put these strings is a separate file, how do I tell the Eclipse editor that they are right-to-left text.

I tried eclipse -dir rtl but that puts all of Eclipse in RTL mode which is not the behavior I looking for.

Comment: did you ever work this out?  I have the same issue, although all the browsers show it fine...

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to carefully use `StringBuilder.reverse()` to manipulate the strings as needed after they are read in.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29

You could also write some simple string manipulation methods as helpers to handle whatever special needs you have.

This page, found in a quick google search, seems to have some interesting info on how Java handles and renders Hebrew: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/hebrew.html

Comment: My issue is not a code issue, but strictly an eclipse editor issue. I can paste the strings in the eclipse editor but it aligns them left-to right and reverses the punctuation etc.

Comment: @Tori, ah, okay, I didn't understand the original question. So, what you want is to view your code in left-to-right mode but the files containing Hebrew in right-to-left mode? The only thing I can suggest is to get a different editor to use for the Hebrew and keep it open in another window.